# Usage of '\0' in various protocols or How can i find a good separator?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm building up a nice application in python from the bottom up that allows encrypted communication between peers. This application able users to dynamically install new plugins and therefore new protocols.

How is used '\0' among common socket operations ? Is it a good separator or should I use something else ?

I would like to be able to manage my own socket code which prevents me from using libs that abstract those bytes constructions.

By the way I'm using Python 3 so all data sent or received is encoded. I'm using utf-8 by default.

Comment: Your question doesn't read like you should be creating anything crypto related intended to be actually used.

Comment: It does not, but I wont tell people communicate on un-encrypted canal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NUL-Byte (b'\0') has been and still is commonly used in binary protocols as separator or when transferring numbers (e.g.: 1 as a 32 bit integer is b'\x01\x00\x00\x00'). Its usage can therefor be considered completely safe with socket implementations on all platforms.

When encoding and decoding strings in Python 3 however, I'd recommend you insert those NUL-Bytes after encoding your string to bytes and stripping them (on the receiver side) before decoding your strings to Unicode.

Comment: Thanks, that's what i'm doing thanks for the answer !